# How to create a strongly type view when I have join in query which I am using in Action method?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

I am working with a action method in which I add a linq query with joins. Now I want to add view for this action method. But the problem is this the linq query is getting data from two entity models and I want to select strongly type view then which class I  have to add for this. Here is the Action Method

```
public ActionResult Marks(int id)
        {
            var marksjoin = (from a in db.TbStudent
                             join b in db.TbMarks on a.StudentId equals b.StudentId
                             select new
                                 {

                                     a.StudentName,
                                     b.StudentId,
                                     b.Hindi,
                                     b.English,
                                     b.SocialStudy,
                                     b.Science,
                                     b.Maths,
                                     b.Total
                                 }).ToList();

           // var marks = db.TbMarks.Where(m => m.StudentId == id).SingleOrDefault();
            if (marksjoin == null)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("PostMarks");
            }
            else
            {
                return View(marksjoin);
            }
```

Now I am getting the data from two entity models and how can I create a strongly type view for this ?

Comment: Create a new view model containing each of those 6 properties and use `... select new MyViewModel { StudentName = a.StudentName, .... }).ToList()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Query projection explained](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee473425(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
var marksjoin = (from a in db.TbStudent
                         join b in db.TbMarks on a.StudentId equals b.StudentId
                         select new StudentType
                             {
                               StudentName = b.StudentName,
                               StudentId =  b.StudentId,
                               // etc
                             }).ToList();

  public class StudentType {
   public string StudentName { get; set; }
   public int StudentId { get; set; }
   // etc...
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a new Type (resulting) and then dump your LINQ output into that Type:-

```
public class NewType 
{
    public List<Item> Items1{ get; set; }
    public List<Item> Items2{ get; set; }
    public string Items3{ get; set; }
    ............and so on
}
```

Then pass this 'NewType' as strong type to your view.